# Realtek ALC282 clicking and popping

Tags: sound, realtek

I have recently got a new laptop Teclast F5 which has a few recurring issues with Ubuntu.

I am currently using Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 but I was having the same issues with Kubuntu 19.10.

When I boot the system and shutdown I get loud clicks/pops from the speaker is there a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a common problem found in linux modules enabling support for various audio hardware. The most sensible thing to do in this case is writing a bug report. The exact same issue has been fixed a short while ago for most creative based sound cards.

Comment: So no fix yet ?

Answer (score 0):

[note: you need to be root for this].

Open file in console using: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf [or, use Dolphin, open with Kate.]

Add the following line at the bottom of the page:

options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N

save and reboot.